# In statistics, why is the symbol μ used for both the population mean and the expected value?

Tags: statistics

I'm studying statistics using an introductory book and it mentioned these:

> "The Greek symbol μ is the population mean."
>
> "When evaluating the long-term results of statistical experiments, we
>   often want to know the “average” outcome. This “long-term average” is
>   known as the mean or expected value of the experiment and is denoted
>   by the Greek letter μ."

Why do they use the same symbol and what's the difference between the two?

Comment: Because the mean of a random variable is the same as its expectation $E(X) = \mu_x.$

Comment: Personally I would not choose for $\mu$ as notation of population mean. The notation gives the impression that we are dealing with some real number which is not the case. The population mean is a random variable.

Comment: @drhab No, the population mean $\mu$ is not a random variable, but a fixed number (a parameter). The sample mean $\bar{X}$ is a random variable (a statistic) when the sample values are considered random variables. But the sample mean $\bar{x}$ of a given sample is a fixed number, and thus not a random variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all to answer a question you didn't ask, $\mu$ is the Greek equivalent of the latin $m$, which stands for mean.

Now for the question you *did* ask. If you have a random variable $X$, and let's assume $X$ is positive for simplicity, then you always have a mean $\mathbb EX$ (which could be infinite). The mean is computed mathematically, by integrating against the probability density function. Thus, both the variable $X$ and the mean $\mu=\mathbb EX$ are theoretical quantities. They describe the statitician's model of the quantity of interest.

On the other hand, the way experiments commonly work is that we collect a sequence of samples to try to nail down a more accurate model. Now the experiment as a whole can be thought of as a single random object, described mathematically by a probability distribution (or better yet, measure) on an infinite sequence space. The actual measurements taken can be written as an infinite sequence $(X_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}$. Now our model will usually posit that the measurements we take all have the same distribution ($X_i$ and $X_j$ have the same law, for all $i$ and $j$) and that the measurements are independent. In this case, the central limit theorem guarantees that if you compute the sample mean
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{n},
$$
this *a priori* random quantity will in fact converge (with probability $1$) to the theoretical mean $\mathbb EX_1$.

Thus, in the limit of a very large number of samples, there ceases to be a distinction between the theoretical mean of a single variable, and the sample mean of the whole population.

Comment: +1 Nice explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Consider we have the data {x1, x2, x3, x4} with probabilities {p1, p2, p3, p4}

Expected value:
$$E(x) = x1*p(x1) + x2*p(x2) + x3*p(x3) + x4*p(x4)$$

if probabilities are the same then: 
$E(x) = \frac{\sum xi}{4}$ that is the same as Mean (average of xis

if probabilities are not the same, then:
the average of xis would be their weighted sum and that is again like E(x)